# VF page buttons/link not clickable in Community

Tags: visualforce, community

I have create a simple vf page and added that page into Community home page. But the page buttons are not clickable.

```
<apex:page >
      <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.New)}" id="LeadButton" value="New Lead"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.New)}" id="AccountButton" value="New Account"/>
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.New)}">Create New Account</apex:outputLink>
      </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

What am i doing wrong?

I just wanted to replicate the Global Action buttons on VF page and add that vf page on community.

Preview of the community home page with vf page :

[image]

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions for creating new records? The [**documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm) mentions this -- Note that command buttons associated with the save, edit, or delete actions in a standard controller are **rendered only if the user has the appropriate permissions**. Likewise, **command buttons associated with the edit and delete actions are rendered only if a record is associated with the page.**

Comment: I have added that vf page and previewing the community with vf page.....so being an admin previewing the home page of community. So i don't think thats the problem here.  Also the buttons are visible but NOT CLICKABLE.

Comment: Formatting notes: backticks (```) are great for `inline code`, but handle line breaks poorly. Use the `{}` code bracket icon to indent any highlighted code 4 spaces, which keeps line breaks without those blank lines between the text.

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar, why are you not creating a Lightning Component instead?

Comment: I haven't learned Lightning components yet......If this problem is not fixable in vf then today i might start learning it.

Comment: What is the template that you have used? Can you provide more details as how your community is implemented?

Comment: Template used is Partner Central.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue where the buttons are disabled in Preview mode.

So here's what I found:

If you click on the "Preview" button while being in your Community Builder, those are disabled (as you reported).

To overcome this, if you select the option "Preview in a new tab" (as in the screenshot below), I was able to see the buttons enabled.

I am not quite sure about this behavior, but this is how it worked for me.

[image]

---

**Recommendation** -- Because you are using a Lightning Template here and that you are trying to customize things on your home page, better go for a Lightning Component which will allow you with more flexibility in what you want to achieve and that you won't need to customize much from UI perspective as you will get the lightning look and feel out of the box in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the information....And yes i have started learning the lightning component. This will be my first lightning component :)